# Ajax call doesn't pass object to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a string to an IActionResult function in an asp.net core 3.1 controller.

Ajax:

```
function CreateApprover() {
    const input = {
        PlantId: $('#ddlPlant').val(),
        UserId: $('#ddlUser').val(),
        CategoryId: $('#ddlCategory').val()
    };

    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(input);
    console.log(jsonData);

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: jsonData,
        traditional: true,
        method: "POST",
        url: "@Model.CreateUrl",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                
            dialogDiv.dialog('close');                
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log('Request Status:');
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log('Status Text:');
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Network Info:

[image]

[image]

C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateApprover(IFormCollection keyValues, [FromBody]ApproversCreateModel input)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    public class ApproversCreateModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int PlantId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

The payload looks correct, and breakpoints are hit in the controller method, but the input param is always null, and the keyValues parameter has no data. What am I missing?

Comment: is it because your model is expecting int and you are passing in string?

Comment: maybe try PlantId: parseInt($('#ddlPlant').val()),   etc.

Comment: Your example works for me. The IFormCollection will not be populated if you're not sending a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" payload -- but it's redundant with your json data (unless it's additional fields). Maybe there's something in the view you are not showing us. How are you binding the CreateApprover js function?

Comment: @BryanDellinger that was the issue. If you want to write an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: try to remove     traditional: true,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Bryan Dellinger,

> maybe try PlantId: parseInt($('#ddlPlant').val()), etc.